# Bash aliases with function in vars

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I do not understand what happens here.

What I try to achieve:

When I call an alias I would like to have

- output who and where called this, like the CLI does
- output the actually commands behind the alias
- execute the commands behind the alias.

Example:

```
# The prefix to be re-used.
__PREFIX='$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)\$'

# The commands to execute in a var to be able to print them too.
FOO="echo 'foo' && echo 1"
BAR="echo 'bar' && echo 2"
BAZ="echo 'baz' && echo 3"

# Define aliases
# echo the prefix and the command that will be executed, 
# and the execute the commands.
alias FOO='echo ${__PREFIX}'" '${FOO}' && ${FOO}"
alias BAR='echo ${__PREFIX}'" '${BAR}' && ${BAR}"
alias BAZ='echo ${__PREFIX}'" '${BAZ}' && ${BAZ}"
```

I found out that I have to use `$(pwd)` in single quotes `'` to call it and not "print" it into the alias.

The `FOO` example above prints:

```
username@notebook:~$ 
$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)\$ echo foo && echo 1
foo
1
```

When I change the `FOO` example to

```
alias FOO='echo $(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)\$'" '${FOO}' && ${FOO}"
```

then it works:

```
username@notebook:~$ 
username@notebook:/home/username$ echo foo && echo 1
foo
1
```

**Question:** how can I have the whoami, hostname and pwd in a var, and then use it in an alias?

Comment: Why would you use an alias for any of this _at all_ instead of just jumping direct to a function? ("If you have to ask, use a function instead" has been core to the #bash IRC channel's factoid on aliases for decades).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

Comment: Alias logic aside, your problem is that expansions aren't recursive. Try it on the command line: `__PREFIX='$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)\$' ; echo ${__PREFIX}`. After __PREFIX is expanded, bash does not go back and check its contents for more expansions.

Comment: (and it's essential that it doesn't: you wouldn't want something that echos a filename or a log line to let anyone who can control that filename or the log's content to run arbitrary commands)

Answer (score 1):

*Don't*. It's strictly possible to run strings from variables as commands, but unless done very cautiously it's [very bad practice for security reasons](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Instead, store commands as functions (which you can conditionally redefine and update just as you might update a variable).

```
# note that running hostname and whoami over and over is very inefficient; don't do this.
log_prefix() { printf '%s@%s:%s$ ' "$(whoami)" "$(hostname)" "$PWD"; }
log_cmd() { printf '%q ' "$@"; printf '\n'; }
log_and_run() { log_prefix; log_cmd "$@"; "$@"; }
```

If you would otherwise want to programatically define aliases, you can do the same thing for functions (though it takes some care not to invoke the previously-referenced security problems):

```
# note that getting this wrong could cause serious security problems
# consequently, it's very carefully written; don't make changes without understanding them
wrap_cmd() {
  local wrapper_name cmd_content def_cmd
  wrapper_name=$1; shift
  printf -v cmd_content '%q ' "$@"
  printf -v def_cmd '%q() { log_and_run %s "$@"; }' "$wrapper_name" "$cmd_content"
  eval "$def_cmd"
}
```

With the above defined, you can use it as:

```
$ wrap_cmd sayhi echo hello # create 'sayhi' to run 'hello world'
$ sayhi world               # and test it! (below is output)
user@host:/home/user$ echo hello world
hello world
```

...and you can also redefine the `log_prefix` function even after commands have been wrapped, in the same way you intend to update `__PREFIX`:

```
$ log_prefix() { printf %s "NEW PREFIX HERE: "; }
$ sayhi world
NEW PREFIX HERE: echo hello
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate the expansion to get another expansion:

```
alias FOO='eval "echo ${__PREFIX}"; echo "${FOO}"; eval "${FOO}"'
```

Comment: You're `eval`ing not just `${FOO}` itself but also all the remaining arguments. That's going to lead to a lot of surprises.

Comment: ...let's say that `FOO` is something like `ls -l`. `ls -l *.txt` is safe no matter what the filenames are. By contrast, `eval ls -l *.txt` in a directory with a file named `$(rm -rf ~).txt` is going to cause pain and suffering.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy then a ending ';' will make the trick. Or am I missing what you meant?

Comment: ...at the expense of the alias no longer being able to pass through arguments at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ahah right, but that's the fun of expansion isn't it?

Comment: I'm too old and jaded to consider leaving pitfalls and traps for the unwary "fun".

Comment: (...speaking of which, also think about `eval "${FOO}"` with the quotes -- doesn't fix the problem with user-provided arguments not always being eval-safe, but it does close off some corner cases when your `FOO` doesn't evaluate back to its original contents when word-split, glob-expanded, and then re-joined back to a single string)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I designed it this way first. I have to answer it like this back then.